# What is the difference between `java -Dspring.profiles.active -jar xxx.jar` and `java -jar xxx.jar --spring.profiles.active`

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

What is the difference between `java -Dspring.profiles.active  -jar  xxx.jar`   and  `java -jar  xxx.jar --spring.profiles.active`

I konw -D is JVM System Parameter  but,   what is -- ? and who define it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--` is something spring boot specific. Spring boot application reads this parameter.

`-Dpring.profiles.active` is handled as a System property, spring can handle it, any place in application (even non spring driven) can access it with `System.getProperty`, `--spring.profiles.active` is handled internally by spring as command line argument, both will work.